# `[NSThread isMainThread]` always returns YES

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

This code

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
      NSLog(@"Main Thread? %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);
});
```

shows that I'm in the main thread. Even doing this:

```
queue = dispatch_queue_create("nonMainQueue", NULL);
```

still reports that I'm in the main queue. This is, it seems, [because I'm using `dispatch sync`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972048/dispatch-sync-always-scheduling-a-block-on-main-thread)

**Does this mean that my code is the same as not using dispatch_sync at all?** Also: what's the point of dispatch_sync if it does nothing at all, then?

Comment: Queues != Threads.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII that's the issue. I'm actually seeing (or imagining) an increase in performance using dispatch_sync. Am I out of my mind (since `isMainThread` returns YES in all cases)?

Comment: try using `dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()` instead. You are not out of your mind, I promise :)

Comment: Thanks Rob, I would try that if I wanted async. Thanks @RichardJ.RossIII, that's awesome. `    assert(dispatch_get_current_queue() != dispatch_get_main_queue() && "this better not be main");`

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII would you be so kind as to make that an answer, since you've found the hole in my knowledge? Thanks!

Comment: `dispatch_get_current_queue` is deprecated. Fine for diagnostic purposes, but I wouldn't go putting that in production code.

Comment: Thanks Rob, is there a non-deprecated way to check? I'll remove it anyway, but developers do forget.

Comment: [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/710745) you have thread in apple dev forums where guys from apple are describing why it is deprecated and how to deal with it

Comment: @Yar BTW, you ask, "Does this mean that my code is the same as not using `dispatch_sync` at all? Also: what's the point of `dispatch_sync` if it does nothing at all, then?" IMHO, there is no point in `dispatch_sync` to a global queue. Async, sure, but not sync. The benefit of `dispatch_sync` is exhibited when dispatching to your own serial queue which is managing some shared resource. `dispatch_sync` is invaluable tool in this scenario (but probably few others).

Comment: @Rob, I'm finding that, though it's executing on the same thread, it's actually MUCH faster (no real measurements of that). Am I hallucinating? [feel free to say yes] If I make the code async, then everything gets out of order and I'd need to find another solution.

Comment: I've broken this out to a separate q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742184

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because queues are not threads, in order to check if you are on the main 'queue', you must use different code, something similar to this:

```
if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   NSLog(@"On Main Thread!");
}
```

Just note that `dispatch_get_current_queue` is deprecated, and is subject to be completely removed in a later iOS/Mac OS version.

Comment: that's amazing, thanks for seeing my error. Sometimes the OP doesn't have a clue ;) Any non-deprecated options for `dispatch_get_current_queue`?

Comment: @Yar unfortunately not. I don't expect it to be going anywhere soon, but you never know when apple will just remove it from the APIs entirely. If that's a huge deal to you, then I would consider filing a bug report with apple requesting it's presence throughout later versions of iOS.

Comment: @Rob read again, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_current_queue): `When called from outside of the context of a submitted block, this function returns the main queue if the call is executed from the main thread. If the call is made from any other thread, this function returns the default concurrent queue.`

Comment: Your comment was in response to my observation that the header file says "When dispatch_get_current_queue() is called on the main thread, it may or may not return the same value as dispatch_get_main_queue(). Comparing the two is not a valid way to test whether code is executing on the main thread." Your code sample seems to be suggesting that if they're the same, you should report "On Main Thread!"

Comment: @Rob that does not exist in the documentation, only in the header files, which may be outdated. When in doubt, I go with the official apple docs and man pages, which specifically state that it *will* return the main queue.

Comment: Fair enough. I personally wouldn't rely on a function listed at deprecated in 6.0 with an explicit admonition that it shouldn't be used in the manner you suggest. And given that the docs failure to acknowledge that it's deprecated doesn't instill confidence there, either. Hey, if it works for you, run with it. I just don't share your confidence in the documentation.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII  Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972048/dispatch-sync-always-scheduling-a-block-on-main-thread. I believe apple docs are contradicting or am I missing something.

Answer (score 5):

This is documented behavior. As an optimization the blocks passed to `dispatch_sync` are executed on the current thread if possible (which is almost always).

Comment: Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972048/dispatch-sync-always-scheduling-a-block-on-main-thread. I believe apple docs are contradicting or am I missing something.

Comment: But if they are executed on the current thread, is the speed of the operation identical to not using `dispatch_sync` at all?

Comment: dispatch_sync against a global concurrent queue is a noop, it executes the specified block directly. This is because the global concurrent queues have no ordering.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from Apple's [GCD guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html), there is no guarantee that dispatch queues will execute on a separate thread. GCD will determine which thread, and if necessary create a new one.

Part of the point is now you do not have to think about threads.

The only thing to keep in mind, is to make sure you are updating UI elements on the main queue, for example:

```
// on background queue
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    someLabel.text = @"My Text";
});
```