# If dispatch_sync does not use a different thread, can it be faster?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I'm running this code

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
      NSLog(@"Main Thread? %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);
      // non-trivial non-UI code here

});
```

The `NSLog` indicates that I'm actually on the main thread, but... my impression is that the non-trivial non-UI code runs much faster if I use `dispatch_sync` (as opposed to nothing).

**If it is running on the main thread, is there any way it could be faster?**

Comment: If you have your non-trivial, non-UI code that you think is faster when you dispatch synchronously to global queue, then why not just time it? Throw in a `NSDate *start = [NSDate date];` before your code, and a `NSTimeInterval elapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start];` at the end, and let us know what you find! I would have thought it was unlikely to be faster, but it's easily verified. I did benchmarking once and didn't find anything observable. And if it's faster in synchronous global queue, then share your code or at least tell us what sort of stuff you're doing.

Comment: Empirically, the answer is what you'd think: no new thread, no performance increase. Hmmm...

Answer (score 4):

The global concurrent GCD queues have no ordering, passing one of them to dispatch_sync() is a noop and dispatch_sync() will just execute the specified block directly in this case, as if you had written

```
^{...}();
```

Comment: What does "is a noop" mean? Thanks

Comment: it means that dispatch_sync() does nothing in this case aside from executing the block.

Comment: Thanks. So is it safe to check if I'm not on the main THREAD to see if I should switch? In other words, will an async_dispatch to a non-main queue always result in me not being on the main THREAD, too? I think so.

Comment: A block dispatch_async()d to a queue will only ever execute on the main thread if that queue is the main queue, or a queue targeted directly or indirectly at the main queue (via dispatch_set_target_queue()).
This is not true if you call dispatch_main(), in that case there is no main thread.

Comment: Now I'm doing `if ([NSThread isMainThread]) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), block); else block();` and it seems like it's all groovy so far. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

By limiting the number of threads running, technically sure you may improve performance, however this isn't recommended. If you have a task that will take a substantial amount of time (substantial meaning, will the user experience be affected by an unresponsive UI) then just use a new thread using `dispatch_async` or an inline block (closure). The best option is to optimize your algorithm to improve the length of your task.

You won't notice a significant enough difference in speed by running on the main thread.