# Dispatch to concurrent queue results in execution on main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

Apple's GCD documentation states the following:

> GCD provides and manages FIFO queues to which your application can
>   submit tasks in the form of block objects. Blocks submitted to
>   dispatch queues are executed on a pool of threads fully managed by the
>   system. No guarantee is made as to the thread on which a task
>   executes. GCD offers three kinds of queues:

Does this mean that even if I issue a request such as

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{...});
```

it could result in the block of code to be executed on the main thread? In that case, it seems that calling dispatch_sync with a concurrent queue on main thread can result in a deadlock situation in which the main thread is stuck waiting for itself.

Is my interpretation of the GCD documentation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it appears that dispatch_sync to a global queue can mean executing code on the main thread if the caller is on the main thread. The documentation for dispatch_sync explains:

> As an optimization, this function invokes the block on the current thread when possible.

[dispatch_sync always scheduling a block on Main Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972048/dispatch-sync-always-scheduling-a-block-on-main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Since dispatch_sync waits for the block to finish, it doesn't really make much difference whether the block is executed on a concurrent thread or the main thread; the main thread is blocked anyway.

So calling dispatch_sync from the main thread effectively blocks the main thread until the block is finished and therefore is a bad idea unless the block executes for a short time only.